# How to \maketitle in standalone

Tags: titles, standalone

`\maketitle` does not seem to play very well with the `standalone` class. This document

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\title{Standalone does not like titles}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
\end{document}
```

yields the error

```
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.5    \maketitle
```

Is it possible to use them together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I'm not sure why you would, but yes. Add `varwidth` as a class option.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\title{Standalone does not like titles}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why? To distribute parts of the document with a beautiful title page. The additional titles will be ignored in the composed main document, because only the first `\maketitle` in a document has an effect. Thanks for the quick solution.